# Mac OS X Terminal: Run Song when Computer is Asleep?

Tags: macos, audio, terminal, sleep

How should one write the

```
afplay "Song/Here"
```

command in terminal on Mac OS X, in order for it to run when the computer is in sleep mode? In other words, through only terminal, how can one play a song/sound of sorts when the computer is asleep?

Comment: On OS X you can put just the Display to Sleep with the rest of the computer running. Your music would play like with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Most of the computer's hardware is shut down during sleep, including both the CPU and audio hardware.